# Qt cannot find GL library

Tags: qt, ubuntu

Kubuntu 19.10, Qt Creator 4.10.2
Based on Qt 5.13.2 (GCC 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6), 64 bit)

Qt doesn't see the GL library:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:417: AircraftAlgorithmPack] Error 1
17:05:25: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project AircraftAlgorithmPack (kit: Desktop Qt 5.12.6 GCC 64bit)    When executing step "Make"
```

Suggested answers from google don't work. All packets with `mesa` are installed. All needed packets from Qt are installed too.

Answer (score 3):

you usually need:

> **GLU**: (The OpenGL Utility Library (GLU) is a computer graphics library
>   for OpenGL)
>
> **Mesa** (also called Mesa3D and The Mesa 3D Graphics Library, is an open
>   source software implementation of OpenGL)
>
> **FreeGLUT** (open-source alternative to the OpenGL Utility Toolkit (GLUT)
>   )

so just do:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev
```

and everything will be fine-

Answer (score 2):

I already had `libgl-dev` installed, but it appeared to have "lost" the symbolic link from `libGL.so` to `libGL.so.1` (which is another symlink), perhaps in one of many rolling upgrades.

It could have been fixed with `ln -s`, but it sufficed to do:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libgl-dev
```